# Bacula v3 + Windows 2008 = Access is denied

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, permissions, bacula

We’re currently testing an upgrade to Bacula 3.0.1 to resolve some issues we’ve been experiencing with Windows 2008 servers.

Since upgrading I have managed to fix problems we were having with VSS and what seems like junction points being created but now we’re getting a fairly bizarre error when attempting to run full and incremental backups (see below).

**Server:** Hyper-V VPS running Windows Datacentre 2008 X86

I have tested this on dedicated servers and the problems are replicable.

```
Could not open directory "C:/Users/Administrator/My Documents/My Videos": ERR=Access is denied.
Could not open directory "C:/Documents and Settings/Default/Application Data": ERR=Access is denied.
Could not open directory "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temporary Internet Files": ERR=Access is denied.
Etc...
```

The directories themselves have default permissions i.e. SYSTEM with full control, administrators etc.. and Bacula is running as an administrator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traversing Windows 2008's (and Vista's, and Windows 7's) backwards-compatibility links doesn't really work as expected. Why is a question for MS.

Each of the examples in the block you provided requires these links:

```
Could not open directory "C:/Users/Administrator/My Documents/My Videos": ERR=Access is denied.
```

Should be C:/Users/Administrator/Videos

```
Could not open directory "C:/Documents and Settings/Default/Application Data": ERR=Access is denied.
```

Should be C:/Users/Default/AppData

Note that many apps that used this path now use the C:/ProgramData/ directory (which used to be C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data).

```
Could not open directory "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temporary Internet Files": ERR=Access is denied.
```

Should be C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files

It's a pain, but Bacula should work just fine in Windows 2008 as long as the paths are set to the new style.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Windows well but maybe that is becouse this path are some kind of windows links?
And secund thing VSS. Maybe try disable them?